# How to draw 3d object javascript

Tags: javascript, 3d, point

I am making a simple JavaScript program that draws a rotated prism. I have vectors that contain x, y and z coordinates of every point and to which point they are connected. The problem I am having is I cannot find the perfect way to compare the dots in 2d. When the figure rotates, it has little, but still visible, defects and it looks like the lines become longer and shorter. I will paste the important parts of the code.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas-id");
canvas.width = 1200;
canvas.height = 500;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var dx=[],dy=[],dz=[],dh=[],dgo=[],h=10,ang=10*Math.PI/360;
var pause=false;
for(var i=0;i<h/2;i++){
    dx[i]=Math.cos(i/h*4*Math.PI+Math.PI/4)*70.71;
    dy[i]=Math.sin(i/h*4*Math.PI+Math.PI/4)*70.71;
    console.log(i/h*2*360);
    dz[i]=150;
    dh[i]=3;
    dgo[i]=[];
    dgo[i][0]=i+h/2;
    dgo[i][1]=i+1;  
    dgo[i][2]=i-1;

    dx[i+h/2]=Math.cos(i/h*4*Math.PI+Math.PI/4)*70.71;
    dy[i+h/2]=Math.sin(i/h*4*Math.PI+Math.PI/4)*70.71;
    dz[i+h/2]=250;
    dh[i+h/2]=3;
    dgo[i+h/2]=[];
    dgo[i+h/2][0]=i;
    dgo[i+h/2][1]=i+h/2+1;
    dgo[i+h/2][2]=i+h/2-1;
    if(i==h/2-1){
        dgo[i][1]-=h/2;
        dgo[i+h/2][1]-=h/2;
    }
    if(i==0){
        dgo[i][2]+=h/2;
        dgo[i+h/2][2]+=h/2;
    }
}
window.addEventListener("mouseup", function (args) {    
    pause=!pause;
}, false);
function abs(a){
    if(a>=0) return a;
    return -a;
}
function pit(x1,y1,x2,y2){
    return Math.sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2)+(y1-y2)*(y1-y2));
}
function rotate(x,y,z){
    for(var i=0;i<h;i++){
        var m=Math.atan2(dx[i]-x,dz[i]-z)/2/Math.PI*360-90,dis=pit(dx[i],dz[i],x,z);
        if(m>0) m-=360
        dx[i]=x+Math.cos(abs(m)/360*2*Math.PI+ang)*dis;
        dz[i]=z+Math.sin(abs(m)/360*2*Math.PI+ang)*dis;
    }
}
function update() {
    if(!pause)rotate(0,0,200)
    setTimeout(update, 10);
}
function line(x1,y1,x2,y2){
    if((x1>0 && y1>0 && x1<canvas.width && y1<canvas.height) || (x2>0 && y2>0 && x2<canvas.width && y2<canvas.height))
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
    ctx.lineTo(x2,y2);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}
function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    for(var i=0;i<h;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<dh[i];j++){
            if(dz[i]>0 && dz[dgo[i][j]]>0)
                line(dx[i]/Math.sqrt(dz[i])*10+canvas.width/2,dy[i]/Math.sqrt(dz[i])*10+canvas.height/2,
                     dx[dgo[i][j]]/Math.sqrt(dz[dgo[i][j]])*10+canvas.width/2,dy[dgo[i][j]]/Math.sqrt(dz[dgo[i][j]])*10+canvas.height/2);
        }
    }
console.log(ctx.translate(0,0,10));
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
draw(); 
update();
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjMaaJ Dones't look bad, what defects are you seeing?

Comment: The elongation you are seeing is likely just perception of perspective.

Comment: it sometimes look good, but i want to know is there specific formula . i mean if there are diferent figures, it look stupid :/